# How to translate a page in Angular? ex. eng to arabic

Tags: ngx-translate

[Am using @ngx translator but I'm getting error. I need to use translator dropdown at footer and the translator should reflect in all pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7Y59.png)

Answer (score 0):

> like this the services .. it works

```
loadTranslations(...args: Locale[]): void {
        const locales = [...args];

        locales.forEach(locale => {
            
        
            this.translate.setTranslation(locale.lang, locale.data, true);

            this.langIds.push(locale.lang);
        });

        // add new languages to the list
        this.translate.addLangs(this.langIds);
    }

    
    setLanguage(lang) {
        if (lang) {
            this.translate.use(this.translate.getDefaultLang());
            this.translate.use(lang);
            localStorage.setItem('language', lang);
        }
    }

    
    getSelectedLanguage(): any {
        return localStorage.getItem('language') || this.translate.getDefaultLang();
    }
```

> and  the constructor

```
import { locale as arLang } from './i18n/ar';

import { locale as frLang } from './i18n/fr';

constructor(private translationService: TranslationService,
                             ) {
    
            // register translations
            this.translationService.loadTranslations(arLang,  frLang);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For localization/internationalization of your app, angular has i18n. It handles all static text of your app and translates with any of your locale. For that you need to include equavalent translated text in $Yourlocale.xlf file.

For some reference:

#### Translate addition [i18n](https://angular.io/guide/i18n)

1. Addition in template

   - Add `i18n` tag :`<div i18n>Some text</div>`
   - Add `i18n-x` tag to component attribute :

     - `<some-component i18n-titleProp="title" titleProp="some text""></some-component>`
     - `<input i18n-placeholder="placeholder"" placeholder="some text""></input>`
2. Addition in ts file [i18n-polyfill](https://github.com/ngx-translate/i18n-polyfill)

   - Add `i18n` to class constructor :`constructor(private i18n: I18n) {}`
   - Add `i18n` tag to variable value :

     - `any = [this.i18n('first value'), this.i18n('second value')]`
     - `some = this.i18n('some value')`
3. Creation XLIFF translations files

   - run `npm run i18n`
4. See translation file `/locales/messages.xlf`

   here you need to manually enter the equivalent translated text for transaltion.